# Simple webpage to display all images in a directory on IIS?

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a simple website that will display a thumbnail for every image in a specific folder. The documents will be stored on a Windows 7 Pro computer and hosted using IIS. I'm not having any luck finding code that will work for me, so I'm hoping to find some help here...

Can this be done easily with Javascript or VBScript? Since this is running under IIS, should I be looking at ASP to generate the HTML output?

Images are stored in a directory named "images" within the directory at the root of the website. The default webpage is named "index.html"

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This site is for asking "what is wrong with what I have"... it is **not** for asking "please do it for me". Show us what you have, and what you're struggling with... and you might get a better response

Comment: "*I'm not having any luck finding code that will work for me*". So write the code that will work for your specific situation yourself? If you just go around copy-pasting code, you're going to have a bad time down the line. Also, StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I know this isn't a "please do it for me" website. I'm simply trying to host the photos from my daughters wedding without having to write every <img> and <a> tag by hand.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I eneded up with, which works, but uses a lot of bandwidth since it doesn't use thumbnails:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Our Wedding - Photographer Photos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center><h1>Our Wedding - Photographer Photos</h1></center>

<%
page = request.querystring("page")
size=16
start = page * size
%>

<% ListFolderContents(Server.MapPath("./photographer")) %>
<% 
sub ListFolderContents(path)

    dim fs, folder, file, item, url

    set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set folder = fs.GetFolder(path)

    ' Count number of files
    total = 0
    for each item in folder.Files
        total = total + 1
    next

    Response.Write("<table>")
    p = 0
    c = 0
    for each item in folder.Files
        if ( p >= start ) then
            if ( c mod 4 = 0 ) then Response.write("<tr>" & vbCrLf)
            url = MapURL(item.path)
            Response.Write("<td width=""20%""><a href=""" & url & """><img src=""" & url & """ width=""100%""></a></td>")
            if ( c mod 4 = 3 ) then Response.write("</tr>"  & vbCrLf)
            c = c + 1
        end if
        p = p + 1
        if ( c => size ) then Exit For
    next
    if (c mod 4 <> 0 ) then Response.write("</tr>" & vbCrLf)

    Response.Write("</table>")

    Response.Write("</br><center>")
    if ( page >= 1 ) then Response.Write("<a href=""photographer.asp?page=" & page-1 & """><- BACK</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
    Response.Write("<a href=""index.html""> HOME </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp")
    if ( p < total ) then Response.Write("<a href=""photographer.asp?page=" & page+1 & """>NEXT -></a>")
    Response.Write("</center></br>")

end sub

function MapURL(path)
    dim rootPath, url

    'Convert a physical file path to a URL for hypertext links.

    rootPath = Server.MapPath("/")
    url = Right(path, Len(path) - Len(rootPath))
    MapURL = Replace(url, "\", "/")

end function
%>

</body>
</html>
```